# Actionscript 3: Detect Language from string

Tags: actionscript-3

How do I detect a language from a string? I googled and saw people testing strings with RegExp, which makes sense, but in all answers people still had problems specifying a characters range.

For instance, can you demonstrate how you'd check if a string is in English?

Comment: I think your question might be overly broad. But if you happen to be on a mobile device, you can get the language locale of the device. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS9b644acd4ebe59998b99a90125fc4fecfb-7ffc.html - but determinign if a phrase in english is a big topic

Comment: I think the most simple example of ambiguous detection is "gross" - it can be German for "big" or English. Otherwise, you can try using `translate.google.com` engine by querying it with `auto` language and your string, it should respond with whatever language it detects.

Comment: I'm talking about characters, it's not that big a topic. For instance "c" is a letter that belongs to english, same goes for the word "cobra". I'm talking about extracting language from string according to char codes.

Comment: Vesper - ambiguous detection is not an issue in my case. It's not good for me to make a server request, so google translate won't help. I really need just a simple way to test character codes range.

Comment: Just the char codes won't get you far. Consider the character "ä". 
1) It will make your regular expressions tricky because `\w`, `\W` and `\b` only work with ASCII chars (i.e. A-Za-z). 
2) It poses an ambiguity that's hard to solve because "ä" belongs to German and Swedish as well. 
3) The absence of "ä" does NOT tell you it's NOT German, especially since I could also write "ae" instead of "ä". Both ways are valid but the first could also be Latin.

Comment: I understand, but like I said it's not an issue for me. The reason I need this is to know when strings contain hebrew or arabic so I can change to RTL accordingly.

Comment: The difficulty here is that even something like the letter "c" is ambiguous. You know it's part of the basic Latin alphabet, but you still don't know what language it is. Knowing what language a word like "cobra" belongs to requires dictionaries to look up that word, and it could still be a valid word in multiple languages. It's a difficult problem as you've stated it, even Google Translate gets it wrong sometimes.

Comment: Aha, you want to know whether to render the string as RTL. That may be a much easier problem to answer. I suggest editing your question to specify this. It's a little beyond my expertise so I don't have much to offer, other than I know there are actually control character codes that indicate the direction text should flow: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi-directional_text